# Extruding Plane goes 3D

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms, extrude

I'm new to Blender and am working through a few tutorials via YouTube, but have encountered a problem that isn't shown in the video. When I loop cut then extrude a 2D plane using E then X, it creates extra faces to make the extruded section 3D (as shown in image). Am I doing something wrong or is there an option somewhere I need to change?

Thanks in advance.
Andrew.

[image: As shown.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in face select mode and it appears that you extruded a face along the **Z** axis. Use **Ctrl + Tab** > **Edge** to change to Edge Select Mode to grab and extrude edges. However make sure that you have removed or undone the face extrude operation before this.